# How to force a svelte store subscription to trigger always, even when the new value equals the old value?

Tags: svelte

So in my code I had something like this

```
export const idOfClickedElement = writable<string | null>(null);
```

I was surprised to learn, that nothing happened when an element was clicked two times in a row. I then found out, that svelte intentionally ignores a `mystore.set(newValue)` if the new value is the same as the value already in the store. While this might be good for performance in some cases, it's not what i wanted. I want to get notified on every click, even on 10 clicks in a row, so it's rather a bug than a feature to me.

My workaround was something like this

```
export const idOfClickedElement = writable<{ id: string; randomNumber: number } | null>(null); // add random number to force an update...
```

and on the call site

```
idOfClickedElement.set({ id: id, randomNumber: Math.random() });
```

Which is pretty dirty, but it works.

Are there more sophisticated approaches to this? In my opinion, ideally this would be an important option to have when instantiating a store:

```
export const idOfClickedElement = writable<string | null>(null, true); // second argument is "alwaysUpdate"
```

Edit: The random number was a bit unnecessary, since a new object would be sufficient to trigger the update, but I'd have preferred to keep the simple string.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve here, what is the ID for? A store is probably just the wrong kind of object.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that my components in different locations reactively get updated when an element is clicked. Instead of bubbling events up and down I'm using a store. Which kind of object would you suggest? I mean I could install rxjs, but I guess that's not the idea either.

Comment: try setting the value not to a string but an object, like {value: whateverstringyouresetting}

Answer (score 1):

If you need events, use an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget).

It provides the functions `addEventListener`, `removeEventListener`, and `dispatchEvent`, if you just want to provide one kind of event you can wrap the instance in an object that internally calls those functions.

Also, if you want to disregard that, using an object is enough to not have equality prevent the store from updating:

```js
idOfClickedElement.set({ id })
```

Comment: yeah i noticed that the random number was unnecessary, still would have preferred the plain string. simple enough though. about the event target, i don't think that's the right tool for me since then i can't have easy svelte reactivity with it, so I think I'll stick with the store. I still find the behavior odd :)

Comment: Svelte is about updating the UI performantly, if state does not *change* there should be nothing to update.

Comment: Also, you can easily turn an `EventTarget` into a store, you just need to provide a `subscribe` function.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yeah thinking about the declarative nature of svelte it kind of makes sense. But coming from rxjs where an observable is just something you push into and subscribers then receive the update it's confusing. Do you have a link with an example for the event target usage in svelte?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, you *can* turn an `EventTarget` into a store, but Svelte will again introduce equality checks if you use `$store` to read the value, which on primitive types again prevents updates. If you use `subscribe` instead it will notify with the same values ([example](https://svelte.dev/repl/af6cfc78b9f84bd98177188fbb300ce5?version=3.55.1)).

Comment: Ok, that's interesting! I initially had a subscribe, but then to prevent memory leaks (https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions) and to not have boilerplate code I switched to the the `$: { ...$idOfClickedElement... changeStyle() }` syntax.